# org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I get the below error when I run my Spring project..I followed multiple SO links and implemented everything but still I have the same problem.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

I have attached my project Maven depedencies, deployment assembly and wtpwebapps lib folder to show all the dependencies..

Not sure what else Im missing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Stack

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: Add full stacktrace to yous question please!

Comment: @Jorge:I have added it..

Comment: Try to add the spring-context jar to your dependencies, see this link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/3.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: I added it but still same pobrlme

Comment: Another thing, change the version of your spring web to same as other spring dependencies. Your current version is 3.0.5 and other spring dependencies is 3.2.8 (the spring security is ok since it uses another versioning timeline)

Comment: Still same issue...Spring web is 3.2.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86566/discussion-between-user1050619-and-jorge-campos).

Comment: We should have ContextLoadListener added to our web.xml as   `<listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>` . Please check and add it if its not added.

Comment: Have you tried to create an external tomcat server? Without using eclipse embedded? My guess is that it is using the embedded tomcat but deploing the jars to another place.

Answer (score 1):

You should have this in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you can try:

- Right click on your project
- "Propeties"
- Deployment Assembly
- Add
- Java Build Path Entries
- Maven Dependencies (Selected them all)
- Finish

Comment: Yes I saw them, that's why I add the part of adding all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your project setup shows there is jar file missing or your are pointing to missing jar file in your project build path.

Right click on your project ==> Go to Build Path ==> In Libraries tab..

You can see the jar files missed with red color cross mark delete them (if you need them add those missing jars in your path)

And re-build the project.

Comment: Could you post the full the stack trace, might be there is some different issue & not related to contextloaderlistener?