# Maven does not import packages

Tags: java, maven

Im using Maven to build my dependencies but for some reason the jars are imported but not the packages.

[image]
Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>EmployeeMgmt</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>EmployeeMgmt Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
        <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- database pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate ORM <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring + aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging, slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>EmployeeMgmt</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What you mean with 'the packages' ?

Comment: when you expand the jars all the packages within it should be displayed but its not....

Comment: @Jorge..Its related to the issue...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910510/org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener-classnotfoundexception?noredirect=1#comment51750094_31910510

Comment: Try to use the eclipse package explorer view, then IN the project open the maven dependencies and expand the jar from there. It should be there

Comment: It does not work either

Comment: For all jars or just one? and in what view (left screenshot or right)?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you mean by packages? All jars come with the packages. GO to your .m2/ repository and extract the jars and see. The packages will be available.

Comment: ..for only few jars...The unittest jar is looking good..ie;when I expand the link, I see all the packages listed

Answer (score 0):

try the following step

right-click in your project, then `Maven -> Update Project`

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP was saying even though he has defined POMs the packages couldn't be imported from within the class (POM isn't "recognized" or "imported")

I had this issue using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2

1. Right click on the **project**
2. Hover over **Maven**
3. Hover over **Run Maven**
4. Click **Reimport**

[image]

Comment: Simpler way is the maven tab in the top right, it has this refresh button on it.

Comment: Yes I agree but for some reason that didn't work for me, the POM dependencies in the POM.xml were not red, but when trying to import package within class package wasn't being recognized... this did the trick for me

Comment: It's the same feature on 2 different menus...